# Regex to insert a char before all caps word

Tags: python, regex

Trying to create Regex to achieve this string conversion:

```
GetMQ -> Get_MQ
AllJSON -> All_JSON
JSONOBJ -> JSONOBJ
ServiceHTTP_Secure_Shell -> Service_HTTP_Secure_Shell
```

In python, I tried this:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(?<!\A)(?=([A-Z]{2,}))")  # Not at the beginning, Lookahead ALLCAPS
result = regex.sub('_', given_string)
```

but no success, I got this:

```
Get_MQ
All_J_S_ON
J_A_S_O_N_O_BJ
Service_H_T_TP_Secure_Shell
```

Seems like 2 or more capital letters expression is expending multiple times. How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', '_', text)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
(?!^)(?<=[^A-Z_])([A-Z]+)
```

- `(?!^)` - Negative lookahead should not match start of string
- `(?<=[^A-Z_])` - Positive lookbehind match should be preceded by anything except capital alphabets or _
- `([A-Z]+)` - Match capital alphabets one or more time

replace by

```
_\1
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/NogcVX/1/)